# How do I explain that the instructions count yielded by simpleperf stat, record over same thread are NOT identical?

Tags: android, perf, instructions, multiplexing

I'm an engineer developing something on Android platform, hence using simpleperf is just something normal to assess thread performance. However recently I got caught in a dilemma, I'm wondering which statistics I should use, let's take a look at the following example:

Environment: threadID:27473 running a while-loop executing same thing in the background

i) **>>> simpleperf stat -e instructions -t 27473 --duration 10 --use-devfreq-counters**

```
Performance counter statistics:

#       count  event_name     # count / runtime,  runtime / enabled_time
  421,117,470  instructions   # 1.349 G/sec  (61%)

Total test time: 10.001907 seconds.
simpleperf W cmd_stat.cpp:863] Percentages < 100% means some events only run a subset of enabled time,
probably caused by hardware counter multiplexing (less counters than events).
Try --use-devfreq-counters if on a rooted device.
```

ii) **>>># simpleperf record -g -t 27473 -e instructions --duration 10 -o /sdcard/perf.data -f 4000 -m 8192**

```
Event: instructions (type 0, config 1)
Samples: 1688
Event count: 570506200

Overhead   Command    Pid  Tid
570506200  SomeThread  684  27473
```

I got 2 questions here:

1. How come monitoring the same thread in the same duration (10 seconds) will end up with completely different instructions counts, namely, 421M vs 570M ? Which one is correct?
2. I noticed that the first method has 61% percentage, so I try to "NORMALIZE" the data by this, don't know if I'm doing right: 421M / 0.61 = 688M, still far from conforming to 2nd method 570M, how can I calibrate these 2 statistics?

Thanks for saving me

Comment: The `perf stat` counts are already normalized for the multiplexing, on the assumption that the 61% of the time that was sampled is representative of the rest.  I'm not familiar with `simpleperf` or android-specific stuff, only regular `perf` on x86-64 Linux, so it seems odd that you'd have any multiplexing when counting only a single hardware event.  On my Intel desktop, there are 4 programmable counters per logical core, so any 4 events can be counted without any multiplexing.

Comment: Are you sure CPU frequency was the same for both runs?  Could this be counting kernel+user instructions (including interrupt handlers)?  `perf stat --all-user`, or `-e instructions:u`, would limit to just user-space.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, thx for ur response. The point u mentioned is indeed another thing I'm wondering. Once I use simpleperf stat -a, no multiplexing occurred. So I think perhaps I still got a long long way to research on this issue

Comment: IDK why system-wide / all-CPUs profiling with `-a` would avoid multiplexing.  I'd expect the counters to be per-core, since having each core send counts to a central per-chip counter would be a big bottleneck.